# Can't Change The DatePicker Font Color

Tags: datepicker, swiftui

I have two datepickers, but the font color is white even I set it to be black. Makes them hard to read.

```
                DatePicker(selection: $fromDate.onChange(self.setFromDate(fromdate:)), in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
                    Text("From")
                        .font(.body)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .fixedSize()
                }
                DatePicker(selection: $toDate.onChange(self.setToDate(todate:)), in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
                    Text("To")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .font(.body)
                        .fixedSize()
                }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.accentColor()`

```
DatePicker(selection: $fromDate.onChange(self.setFromDate(fromdate:)), in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
                  Text("From")
                      .font(.body)
                      .foregroundColor(.black)
                      .fixedSize()
}
.accentColor(Color.black)
```